# Gene networks for different tissues?

Tags: gene, biological-networks

I currently work on gene networks and specifically, I analyze the brain gene regulatory network of an insect to understand its sexual behaviour. During a recent presentation, I got asked this question which I just couldn't really tackle in a good manner. The question was why do I study the brain gene network to understand sexual activity when I should be studying the gene network of a sexual organ, for eg: the ovary. I got out saying that since the brain decides behaviour, it would be much better to study the brain GRN. However, I got confused and would like to know if different tissue or organs in the same organism have different gene networks? Any idea regarding the theory is welcomed.

Comment: Of course different tissues have different gene expression - I'd expect that isn't something at all new to you so I'm wondering why you are asking the question? Your response to that somewhat bizarre question seems fine to me, maybe the question asker was trying to lead you into a discussion of how sex organs also affect gene expression in the brain, e.g. via hormone production.

Comment: Check out this [heart development paper](http://dev.biologists.org/content/139/18/3277). What's striking is different programs for varying progenitor cells *within the same tissue*, **and** the presence of core elements from other cell types or tissues such as GATA3, working together to perform unrelated functions. Cell have the capacity to express the same gene network, but how they're regulated differs on a number of variables.